# JPA+hibernate...BiDirectional association... Instead of lnnerJoin, left outer join fired in query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, associations

I have two class named Banneers and BannerGroup.

I want to create a bidirectional relationship.
In my case, A BannerGroup can have many Banners and Many Banners belongs within a same BannerGroup.

Mysql tables are...

```
mysql> desc Banners;
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra                       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+
| banner_id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment              | 
| banner_name      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                             | 
| banner_group_id  | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                             | 
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-----------------------------+

mysql> desc Banner_Group;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------+-----------------------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default        | Extra                       |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------+-----------------------------+
| group_id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL           | auto_increment              | 
| group_name          | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL           |                             | 
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------+-----------------------------+
```

My model class is like this...

```
Class Banners
{
    private Integer bannerId;
    private String bannerName;
    private BannerGroup bannerGroupDO;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "banner_id")
    public Integer getBannerId() {
        return bannerId;
    }

    public void setBannerId(Integer bannerId) {
        this.bannerId = bannerId;
    }

    @Column(name = "banner_name")
    public String getBannerName() {
        return bannerName;
    }

    public void setBannerName(String bannerName) {
        this.bannerName = bannerName;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "banner_group_id",  nullable = false)
    public BannerGroup getAffiliateBannerGroup() {
        return bannerGroupDO;
    }

    public void setAffiliateBannerGroup(BannerGroup bannerGroupDO) {
        this.bannerGroupDO = bannerGroupDO;
    }
}

Class BannerGroup{

    private int group_id;
    private int group_name;
    private List<Banners> banners;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    public Integer getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(Integer groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    @Column(name = "group_name")
    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="bannerGroupDO", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Banners> getBanners() {
        return banners;
    }

    public void setBanners(List<Banners> banners) {
    this.banners = banners;
    }
}
```

Now, when i am trying to get **List** which is **lazily** loaded from the BannerGroup...

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from com.abc.xyz.model.BannerGroup ");
```

i got this...

```
Query1: Hibernate: select b0_.group_id as group1_297_, b0_.group_name as group9_297_ from BANNER_GROUP b0_
Query2: Hibernate: select banner0_.banner_group_id as banner19_1_, banner0_.banner_id as banner1_1_, banner0_.banner_group_id as banner19_296_0_ from BANNERS banner0_ where banner0_.banner_group_id=?
```

This works OK.

But Now, when i am trying to get **BannerGroup** which is **eagerly** loaded from the Banners...

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from com.abc.xyz.model.Banners ab where ab.bannerGroupDO.groupId = :GroupId ");
```

i got this...

```
Hibernate: select b0_.banner_id as banner1_296_, b0_.banner_group_id as banner19_296_ from BANNERS b0_, BANNER_GROUP b1_ where b0_.banner_group_id=b1_.group_id and b0_.banner_group_id=? 
Hibernate: select b0_.group_id as group1_297_1_, b0_.group_name as group9_297_1_, b1_.banner_group_id as banner19_3_, b1_.banner_id as banner1_3_, b1_.banner_group_id as banner19_296_0_ from BANNER_GROUP b0_ left outer join BANNERS b1_ on b0_.group_id=b1_.banner_group_id where b0_.group_id=?
```

My questions are

```
1.) why "**left outer join**" ? not an "**inner join**"?
2.) If i want inner join for between Banners and BannerGroup. what should i do?
3.) Decision of join type is depend on what? JPA ? Hibernate? association? or anything else?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an outer join because you have specified to fetch **all** `BannerGroup` entities.

If the persistence provider would use an inner join, all `BannerGroup` entities without `Banners` associations would not be fetched.

This behavoir is a JPA-conforming interpretation of the query 
`from com.abc.xyz.model.BannerGroup`, which is a form of `select b from BannerGroup`

If you want an explicit inner join, adapt your query:

`select b from BannerGroup join b.banners`.

The `inner` keyword is optional, so this query is equivalent:

`select b from BannerGroup inner join b.banners`